Blitz app using Pages router setup problem where api fetching is giving 404 error
I tried setting up a Blitz app named "remotio", and I selected the pages router (not the App router) of nextjs for that. But when I run blitz dev, I get two errors (don't know if both are related):

POST http://localhost:3000/api/rpc/getCurrentUser 404 (Not Found)


            Warning: A title element received an array with more than 1 element as children. In browsers title Elements can only have Text Nodes as children. If the children being rendered output more than a single text node in aggregate the browser will display markup and comments as text in the title and hydration will likely fail and fall back to client renderingat titleat headat Head (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:258:1)at htmlat Html (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:676:132)at MyDocument (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/_document.tsx:12:1)





I was just trying a normal blitz app named "remotio" with Pages router. Everything installed perfectly, but then when I run blitz dev, I ran into the error that I detailed.
So, I began the project with these commands in my VS Code terminal:
npm install -g blitz
blitz new remotio
On this, it asked me for picking few choices:
$ blitz new remotio

√ Pick your new app template » Pages Router – Full Setup: includes DB and auth

√ Install dependencies? ... yes

√ Pick a form library (you can switch to something else later if you want) » React Hook FormThen it downloaded all the essentials of the project. Then, 

cd remotio;

And then when I ran
blitz dev

It showed me this error in the terminal:
                ✔ Next.js was successfully patched with a React Suspense fix
                ✔ Routes manifest was successfully generated
                  ▲ Next.js 14.2.15
                  - Local:        http://localhost:3000
                  - Environments: .env.local, .env
                
                 ✓ Starting...
                 ✓ Ready in 5.2s
                 ○ Compiling / ...
                 ✓ Compiled / in 5.6s (406 modules)
                [Rendering Suspense fallback...: DYNAMIC_SERVER_USAGE] {
                  digest: 'DYNAMIC_SERVER_USAGE'
                }
                 GET / 200 in 15136ms
                 ✓ Compiled /404 in 179ms (410 modules)
                Warning: A title element received an array with more than 1 element as children. In browsers title Elements can only have Text Nodes as children. If the children being rendered output more than a single text node in aggregate the browser will display markup and comments as text in the title and hydration will likely fail and fall back to client rendering
                    at title
                    at head
                    at Head (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:308:1)
                    at html
                    at Html (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:782:132)
                    at MyDocument (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/_document.tsx:11:1)
                 POST /api/rpc/getCurrentUser 404 in 245ms

And in the browser, the site loads up shows for maybe half a second and suddenly then a 404 error page shows up. The console shows this:
Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: https://reactjs.org/link/react-devtools
websocket.js:39 [HMR] connected
hot-reloader-client.js:222 [Fast Refresh] rebuilding
:3000/api/rpc/getCurrentUser:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
hydration-error-info.js:63 Error: Not Found
console.error @ hydration-error-info.js:63
Show 1 more frame
Show less
2useBaseQuery.mjs:69 Uncaught Error: Not Found
hydration-error-info.js:63 The above error occurred in the <UserInfo> component:

    at UserInfo (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/index.tsx:30:103)
    at Suspense
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at main
    at div
    at Layout (webpack-internal:///./src/core/layouts/Layout.tsx:12:11)
    at Home
    at AuthRoot (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@blitzjs/auth/dist/chunks/index.mjs:389:5)
    at _a (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@blitzjs/next/dist/chunks/index-browser.mjs:164:7)
    at WithRouterWrapper (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@blitzjs/next/dist/chunks/index-browser.mjs:156:76)
    at MyApp (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/_app.tsx:49:11)
    at Hydrate (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@tanstack/react-query/build/lib/Hydrate.mjs:30:3)
    at QueryClientProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@tanstack/react-query/build/lib/QueryClientProvider.mjs:47:3)
    at BlitzProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@blitzjs/next/dist/provider.mjs:12:3)
    at BlitzOuterRoot (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@blitzjs/next/dist/chunks/index-browser.mjs:461:111)
    at WithSuperJSON (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@blitzjs/next/dist/chunks/index-browser.mjs:102:104)
    at PathnameContextProviderAdapter (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/adapters.js:81:11)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/pages/ErrorBoundary.js:41:9)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/pages/ReactDevOverlay.js:33:11)
    at Container (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:81:1)
    at AppContainer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:189:11)
    at Root (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:413:11)

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, _a.

I am sharing the README file based on which if any of you need me to share more files, kindly feel free to tell me.
Here is the README.md file:
                [![Blitz.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blitz-js/art/master/github-cover-photo.png)](https://blitzjs.com)
                
                This is a [Blitz.js](https://github.com/blitz-js/blitz) app.
                
                # ****name****
                
                ## Getting Started
                
                Run your app in the development mode.
                
                ```
                blitz dev
                ```
                
                Open [http://localhost:3000](http://localhost:3000) with your browser to see the result.
                
                ## Environment Variables
                
                Ensure the `.env.local` file has required environment variables:
                
                ```
                DATABASE_URL=postgresql://<YOUR_DB_USERNAME>@localhost:5432/remotio
                ```
                
                Ensure the `.env.test.local` file has required environment variables:
                
                ```
                DATABASE_URL=postgresql://<YOUR_DB_USERNAME>@localhost:5432/remotio_test
                ```
                
                ## Tests
                
                Runs your tests using Jest.
                
                ```
                yarn test
                ```
                
                Blitz comes with a test setup using [Vitest](https://vitest.dev/) and [react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/).
                
                ## Commands
                
                Blitz comes with a powerful CLI that is designed to make development easy and fast. You can install it with `npm i -g blitz`
                
                ```
                  blitz [COMMAND]
                
                  dev       Start a development server
                  build     Create a production build
                  start     Start a production server
                  export    Export your Blitz app as a static application
                  prisma    Run prisma commands
                  generate  Generate new files for your Blitz project
                  console   Run the Blitz console REPL
                  install   Install a recipe
                  help      Display help for blitz
                  test      Run project tests
                ```
                
                You can read more about it on the [CLI Overview](https://blitzjs.com/docs/cli-overview) documentation.
                
                ## What's included?
                
                Here is the starting structure of your app.
                
                ```
                remotio
                ├── src/
                │   ├── api/
                │   ├── auth/
                │   │   ├── components/
                │   │   │   ├── LoginForm.tsx
                │   │   │   └── SignupForm.tsx
                │   │   ├── mutations/
                │   │   │   ├── changePassword.ts
                │   │   │   ├── forgotPassword.test.ts
                │   │   │   ├── forgotPassword.ts
                │   │   │   ├── login.ts
                │   │   │   ├── logout.ts
                │   │   │   ├── resetPassword.test.ts
                │   │   │   ├── resetPassword.ts
                │   │   │   └── signup.ts
                │   │   ├── pages/
                │   │   │   ├── forgot-password.tsx
                │   │   │   ├── login.tsx
                │   │   │   ├── reset-password.tsx
                │   │   │   └── signup.tsx
                │   │   └── validations.ts
                │   ├── core/
                │   │   ├── components/
                │   │   │   ├── Form.tsx
                │   │   │   └── LabeledTextField.tsx
                │   │   └── layouts/
                │   │       └── Layout.tsx
                │   ├── pages/
                │   │   ├── _app.tsx
                │   │   ├── _document.tsx
                │   │   ├── 404.tsx
                │   │   ├── index.test.tsx
                │   │   └── index.tsx
                │   └── users/
                │       ├── hooks/
                │       │   └── useCurrentUser.ts
                │       └── queries/
                │           └── getCurrentUser.ts
                ├── db/
                │   ├── migrations/
                │   ├── index.ts
                │   ├── schema.prisma
                │   └── seeds.ts
                ├── integrations/
                ├── mailers/
                │   └── forgotPasswordMailer.ts
                ├── public/
                │   ├── favicon.ico
                │   └── logo.png
                ├── test/
                │   ├── setup.ts
                │   └── utils.tsx
                ├── .eslintrc.js
                ├── babel.config.js
                ├── blitz.config.ts
                ├── vitest.config.ts
                ├── package.json
                ├── README.md
                ├── tsconfig.json
                └── types.ts
                ```
                
                These files are:
                
                - The `src/` folder is a container for most of your project. This is where you’ll put any pages or API routes.
                
                - `db/` is where your database configuration goes. If you’re writing models or checking migrations, this is where to go.
                
                - `public/` is a folder where you will put any static assets. If you have images, files, or videos which you want to use in your app, this is where to put them.
                
                - `integrations/` is a folder to put all third-party integrations like with Stripe, Sentry, etc.
                
                - `test/` is a folder where you can put test utilities and integration tests.
                
                - `package.json` contains information about your dependencies and devDependencies. If you’re using a tool like `npm` or `yarn`, you won’t have to worry about this much.
                
                - `tsconfig.json` is our recommended setup for TypeScript.
                
                - `.babel.config.js`, `.eslintrc.js`, `.env`, etc. ("dotfiles") are configuration files for various bits of JavaScript tooling.
                
                - `blitz.config.ts` is for advanced custom configuration of Blitz. [Here you can learn how to use it](https://blitzjs.com/docs/blitz-config).
                
                - `vitest.config.ts` contains config for Vitest tests. You can [customize it if needed](https://vitejs.dev/config/).
                
                You can read more about it in the [File Structure](https://blitzjs.com/docs/file-structure) section of the documentation.
                
                ### Tools included
                
                Blitz comes with a set of tools that corrects and formats your code, facilitating its future maintenance. You can modify their options and even uninstall them.
                
                - **ESLint**: It lints your code: searches for bad practices and tell you about it. You can customize it via the `.eslintrc.js`, and you can install (or even write) plugins to have it the way you like it. It already comes with the [`blitz`](https://github.com/blitz-js/blitz/tree/canary/packages/eslint-config) config, but you can remove it safely. [Learn More](https://blitzjs.com/docs/eslint-config).
                - **Husky**: It adds [githooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks), little pieces of code that get executed when certain Git events are triggerd. For example, `pre-commit` is triggered just before a commit is created. You can see the current hooks inside `.husky/`. If are having problems commiting and pushing, check out ther [troubleshooting](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=troubleshoot) guide. [Learn More](https://blitzjs.com/docs/husky-config).
                - **Prettier**: It formats your code to look the same everywhere. You can configure it via the `.prettierrc` file. The `.prettierignore` contains the files that should be ignored by Prettier; useful when you have large files or when you want to keep a custom formatting. [Learn More](https://blitzjs.com/docs/prettier-config).
                
                ## Learn more
                
                Read the [Blitz.js Documentation](https://blitzjs.com/docs/getting-started) to learn more.
                
                The Blitz community is warm, safe, diverse, inclusive, and fun! Feel free to reach out to us in any of our communication channels.
                
                - [Website](https://blitzjs.com)
                - [Discord](https://blitzjs.com/discord)
                - [Report an issue](https://github.com/blitz-js/blitz/issues/new/choose)
                - [Forum discussions](https://github.com/blitz-js/blitz/discussions)
                - [How to Contribute](https://blitzjs.com/docs/contributing)
                - [Sponsor or donate](https://github.com/blitz-js/blitz#sponsors-and-donations)

